# Flutter ROW containers

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have many containers in the `Row` and I have to push this blue one as far to the right as possible. Can u Help me? Here is a code and pick underneath.

```dart
Row(
children: [
  Container(
    width: 100,
    height: double.infinity,
    color: Colors.red,
  ),
  SizedBox(width: 50),
  Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Container(
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        color: Colors.yellow,
      ),
      Container(
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        color: Colors.green,
      ),
    ],
  ),
  Container(
    width: 100,
    height: double.infinity,
    color: Colors.blue,
  ),
],
),
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `Spacer()` in between your widgets

```
 Column(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: [
      Container(
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        color: Colors.yellow,
      ),
      Container(
        width: 100,
        height: 100,
        color: Colors.green,
      ),
    ],
  ),
  Spacer(),  // add this
  Container(
    width: 100,
    height: double.infinity,
    color: Colors.blue,
  )
```

Comment: IT works! THANK YOU :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,` on `Row`.

```dart
 body: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
```

Answer (score -1):

Use Expanded with flex property

```
Expanded(
   flex:1,//use how much flex you want
   child:,//use your container
),
```